# How to set up partially fluid layout (IMAGE)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I have a problem with setting up a layout for my design.

I want to have two div's, left and right. And i want them to fill left and right side, but stay in the same position in the center.

Left div will have content only in "always visible" 300px (this page in not for mobile). But  in right DIV I want to have content based on %, to expand with larger screens. And on the smaller screens I don't want to have w horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

Can someone point me to the best solution?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/bhxLe0Ly/1/)

Html will be :

```
<div class="left">Test</div>
<div class="right">Test</div>
```

CSS will be :

```
.left {width:300px; background:#FF0000; min-height:400px; float:left; }
.right { background:#00FF00; min-height:400px;  }
```

Comment: But on higher resolution I would like left div to move to the center and expand, to fill extra space on the left. I think I'll have to use some JavaScript. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution. So, HTML :

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Css:

```
.left { 

  width:300px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;

}

.right {
  width:900px;
  background:red;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
$(window).ready(function() {
            var hWind = $(window).height();
            var wWindow = $(window).width();
            var toDistribute = wWindow - 1200;
            if (toDistribute > 0) {


                var addToBoth = toDistribute/2;
                var lW = $('.left').width();
                var rW = $('.right').width();
                $('.left').width(lW+addToBoth);
                $('.right').width(rW+addToBoth);
                $('.right').css('margin-left',lW+addToBoth);
            }
        });
```